# Application installation error

Tags: software-installation

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NYjj.png)

I'm a beginner using Ubuntu 14.04, and I cannot install VLC player from the store. It says package dependencies cannot be solved. The following pictures show the errors:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please copy-paste that error here.

Comment: vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f vlc`.

Comment: Same error bud :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade',and then i typed 'sudo update-manager -d'.The error is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends vlc'
3. Enter password for sudo

Have you tried to use synaptic package manager to install vlc too?

Hope it will help, Thanks

Comment: it still shows the same error